# Integer factors of rational and irrational numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

While getting familiar with *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic* which can be applied to integers only, I am wondering about the rationals and may be irrationals. Are there any ideas, methods, theorems to find integer factors of a these two sets?

Comment: As [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) suggests, please show some contexts.

Comment: You can't factor a rational $a/b$ uniquely. $42$ is a factor of $a/b$ since $42(1/42)(a/b) = a/b$.

Comment: Any non-zero integer (or rational) is a factor of any other rational. So factorisation of rationals is pretty uninteresting.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco The question has been edited.

Comment: Oh, Thanks @Arthur. This is helpful.

Comment: @JuliusL33t But you can reduce to lowest terms then uniquely factor the numerator and denominator, which yields the analog for fractions.